# referencing a variable with an undefined value

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined, alert

I am trying to alert a variable after a timer ends. The variable is a score with an undefined value as it changes according to interactivity. However, it shows up as undefined.

```
<tr>
   <td id="scoreText">Score:</td>
   <td><input type="text" id="score" readonly></td>
  </tr>
```

The html is created with a text input type that is read only. However, there is no value for me to pull from that I can alert. The score value changes according to interactivity, shown in the code below.

```
  <script>
function hithead(id) {

                if(currentpos!=id) {
                    totalhits+=-1;
                    document.getElementById("score").value=totalhits;
                    document.getElementById(id).checked=false;
                }
                else {
                    totalhits+=1;
                    document.getElementById("score").value=totalhits;
                    launch();
                    document.getElementById(id).checked=false;

                    document.getElementById("theHiddenOne").value=totalhits;

                }

            }



   var showScore = document.getElementById("theHiddenOne").value;

            function showtime(remtime) {
                document.getElementById("timeleft").value=remtime;
                if(playing) {
                    if(remtime==0) {
                        alert('Game Over! \n Your Score is'  + showScore );
                        location.reload();
                    }
                    else {
                        temp=remtime-1;
                        setTimeout("showtime(temp)",1000);
                    }
                } 
            }
</script>
```

The value of the score is determined through the totalhits in the hithead function.

theHiddenOne was created so the value will show up in the html to be referenced to. I have tested this out by creating a console.log, and a value was given. However, I am unable to reference this value in my showScore variable.

Thank you.

```
gamelength=30;
            timerID=null
            var playing=false;
            var numholes=6*10;
            var currentpos=-1;


            function clrholes() {
                for(var k=0;k<60;k++)
                document.getElementById(k).checked=false;
            }





            function play() {

                playing=true;
                clrholes();
                totalhits=0;
                document.getElementById("score").value=totalhits;
                launch();
                showtime(gamelength);


            }


            function launch() {
                var launched=false;

                while(!launched) {

                    mynum=random();

                    if(mynum!=currentpos) {
                        document.getElementById(mynum).checked=true;
                        currentpos=mynum;
                        launched=true;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I can't see `hithead()` or `showtime()` are being called anywhere, if they are not called then `showScore`'s value will stay `undefined`.

Comment: @AhmedHammad I have edited my post to include the entire javascript code. Thie showtime()  was called, but hithead() is not. How would i be able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```js
setTimeout("showtime(temp)",1000)// as a string

//should be like this
setTimeout(showtime.bind(temp),1000)

//or simpler
setTimeout(function(){
showtime(temp)
},1000)
```

Comment: `setTimeout("showtime(temp)",1000)` would still work fine, this isn't the issue